# Out of options: frontend and backend blank page Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.3

**I know that this question is asked many times before but I'm out of options and none of the answers given on Stackoverflow is helping.**

I'm working on migrating a Magento webshop to another server, everything was working fine yesterday until I migrated the *app/etc/modules*, *app/code/community*, *app/code/local*, *js* and *lib* folders. Magento just gave me a blank page after that, I removed those folders (keeping the original Magento files) but all the pages are still blank.

My error logs don't give any detail about why the page isn't loading, and removing the # in the index.php for

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Doesn't work either because the first error that is showing up is a PHP5.3 error because the client runs Magento 1.3.2.1 (fixed by using this tweak: http://spikomoko.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/magento-not-working-on-php-5-3).

Is there anyone with any information because I'm out of options.

Comment: Is developer mode enabled in *index.php* before `Mage::run()` is called? `mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`

Comment: There's probably no errors in your Magento (/var/log) logs, but did you check your server logs? Also, once you re-removed these files, did you flush your cache to make sure nothing was still stored? Can you even get into the backend? If you can't, I would delete all the files in var/cache, var/full_page_cache (if you have it), and the /var/sessions folders. Then try loading the page again.

Comment: Backend was blank, what I'm doing right now is doing everything again. I will reply if I get the same problem again. (The server logs didn't gave any errors). Thanks!

Comment: I had similar problem and it came, because of combination of server configuration and bad coded extension. First, that you have to do is to check the Apache error logs. Second you can just start to disable the local and community modules one by one. My problem came from, that somebody added a blank space before one of the opening <?php tags.

Comment: When the page loads, does it take a few seconds for the request and everything to be made? Or does the blank page load really quickly?

Comment: Directly, within a few milliseconds.

Comment: Oke guys, I just uploaded my js and lib folder again and everything is blank again. Any idea's?

Comment: I have 3 ideas: ( 1 ) check the apache log! ( 2 ) Check the files permissions, because may be you upload the files to your server with different read write permissions. ( 3 ) Give us the url of the live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer.

I extracted my *lib* and *js* folder from a tar.gz file, this replaced the modified *lib/Varien/Object.php* with the original one. Causing a blank page error because the errors are disabled in the Magento index.php.

Comment: I guess, that this problem came from wrong files permissions :)

Comment: It is so frustrating, I could have fixed this yesterday.